# How to update a value in nested array based on the given index and return original array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an index '3_1_0' and the following array:-

```
var fields = [
    {
        name: 'a'
    },
    {
        name: 'b'
    },
    {
        name: 'c'
    },
    {
        name: 'd',
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'd1'
            },
            {
                name: 'd2',
                fields: [
                    {
                        name: 'd2.1'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to extract the element from the above fields array based on the index. so 3_1_0 will extract following

```
{
    name: 'd2.1'
}
```

Update the value from d2.1 to some other value like 'new_d2.1' and attach the updated value at the same index in original fields array and return the updated fields array. How this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the desired result. We start by splitting the index into an array, then reducing to get the result.

We'll use some [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to ensure we'll return `undefined` if no value is found (say our index was '7_10_20').

Once we've found our object, we can set the required property.

```js
const fields = [ { name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }, { name: 'c' }, { name: 'd', fields: [ { name: 'd1' }, { name: 'd2', fields: [ { name: 'd2.1' } ] } ] } ];

const index = '3_1_0'

function setValue(fields, index, property, value) {
    const obj = index.split('_').reduce((acc, key) => { 
       return acc?.[key] || acc?.fields?.[key];
    }, fields);
    // Only update if we actually find anything
    if (obj) { 
        obj[property] = value
    }
}

setValue(fields, '3_1_0', 'name', 'new_d2.1');

console.log("Fields:", fields);
```

Comment: I never notice `arr["0"]` is implicitly converted as the `arr[0]`.

Comment: It's effectively the same thing I believe, one would have to look at the ECMA spec. to see exactly how it should be handled. One could always do a .map after the split like index.split('_').map(n => +n), but I don't think it's strictly necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am looking to get the original array back with name updated to new_d2.1 at 3_1_0 position

Comment: @TerryLennox, Yes. They are the same thing, even happen in the object. I just never notice it before.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback @D.K. I've updated!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{ name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }, { name: 'c' }, { name: 'd', fields: [ { name: 'd1' }, { name: 'd2', fields: [ { name: 'd2.1' } ] } ] } ];

let givenIdxs = "3_1_0";

let indexes = givenIdxs.split("_");

let result = data[indexes[0]];

for(let idx = 1; idx < indexes.length; idx++){
  result = result.fields[indexes[idx]];
}

console.log(result);
```